# Find distinct groups with no common parents

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Given an array $arr$, element $arr[i]$ indicates its parent. If the element has no parent then $arr[i]=-1$. What is the optimal algorithm for finding the minimum number of groups such that no element in each group is a child node (whether directly or indirectly) of any other node in the same group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*arr[]* can be considered a partial order, and the groups you're looking for are then called *antichains*. So, you're looking for a decomposition into a minimum number of antichains of the partial order represented by *arr[]*. According to [Mirsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirsky%27s_theorem), the smallest achievable number of antichains is equal to the length of the longest chain -- that is, the longest path of descendants in the forest (set of trees) represented by *arr[]*. (It's impossible to do better than this, since every element in this longest chain needs to be assigned to a distinct antichain.)

That Wikipedia page also describes a neat way to actually construct an optimal set of antichains, based on the idea that if two elements have the same number of ancestors, neither of them can be an ancestor of the other. In short: Perform BFS on the forest defined by *arr[]*, starting from all root elements (you can do this by initially inserting all such elements into the queue); every layer (set of nodes at the same depth) constitutes one antichain.

Comment: Awesome answer! Two points of clarification, 1/ when first iterating through the array to find the longest antichain is it more time efficient to construct an auxiliary array to hold the chain depth for any given element instead of traversing to the root for every element? 2/ when performing BFS from all root nodes are you assuming you have already constructed the chains from an initial pass through arr[]?

Comment: Happy to help :) (1) You don't need to actually find the longest chain as a separate first step, as this will be found as a side effect of the BFS that determines the groups -- its just the deepest level found. (2) You don't need any data structure representing the chains, just do a regular BFS. For this you will first need to represent edges in a way that BFS can use, e.g., [adjacency list representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).